# Binding a port to a specific network in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, pihole

I run [pihole](https://hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole) on my RPi behind [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) reverse proxy, along with several other proxied containers. I want to:

- map the port 80 of the pihole container to an **internal-only network** (that nginx proxies to public port 80)
- map the port 53 (DNS) to the **default network** (so that it's publicly available).

By default all ports are published on all networks the container is part of, which I'm trying to avoid. In essence I'd like to do this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    hostname: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    networks:
      - default
      - intraonly
    ports:
      - default:53:53/tcp
      - default:53:53/udp
      - intraonly:80/tcp
      - intraonly:443/tcp

[...nginx & other services definitions follow...]

networks:
  intraonly:
    driver: bridge
    internal: true
```

The above **obviously fails**, because the documentation says clearly it expects an **IP address only** in the port definition:

> Specify the host IP address to bind to AND both ports (the default is 0.0.0.0, meaning all interfaces): (IPADDR:HOSTPORT:CONTAINERPORT).

That seems crazy however, as the **IP address changes every time** I rebuild the container. In other places the documentation suggests to **avoid addressing** other containers **by IP address** and chose the symbolic service names (published by DNS) instead.

What am I missing? **What is the right/robust way** to expose a port on a specific interface without hardcoding IP address? (I'm aware I could achieve internal-only ports by using `expose` syntax), but the question of binding ports to specific custom networks still stands.)

Comment: `ports:` are only accessible from outside Docker space, and the IP address you use there is one of the host's interfaces.  `networks:` are only accessible from other containers.

Comment: To clarify the previous comment, nginx can access pihole:80 on the same Docker network bridge without you having any ports specified in the compose file, therefore you seem to only need port 53 mapped to the host

Comment: Doh! Not sure how I managed to miss that in all my passes through the documentation! Makes total sense, thanks!